# Eliminate Duplicate C# Property Bodies

Tags: c#

I am building a large, complex data structure with many interconnected objects. As part of this, I have a situation where I need to create an object before I know the values for all the properties. This is so I can pass a reference to that object around inside of a larger data structure, then change it later to allow all the consumers of that object to get the "updated" values.

Tracking the consumers of each object so I can go update their references means I am A) re-implementing a reference counting garbage collector and B) would require an external consumer to modify a class. For obvious reasons, I don't want to implement a garbage collector (or something similar). and allowing external consumers to modify properties means the object is mutable. Immutability is important because I know that many objects in this data structure are going to wind up in Dictionaries *after* the data structure has been built, but I can safely modify properties until then. Since this is going into a library that will be provided to other users, I **must** block interactions that will break things like invariants for Dictionaries.

I am implementing this "deferred initialization" concept for properties like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private AnotherClass mReference = null;
    public bool Reference
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mReference
        }
        internal set
        {
            if ( this.mReference != null )
            {
                throw new Exception( "This value has already been initialized!" );
            }
            else
            {
                this.mReference = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am allowing anything in the `internal` scope to assign a non-null value to this property exactly once. Once the property has been set, there's no going back.

While C# has a keyword `readonly` that sort of already does this, `readonly` constrains the member to only be assigned to via either a static initializer or a constructor in the same class. But at the time the constructor is called, *I don't know what the value for this property is!*

My problem is I am now using this exact pattern across multiple classes, and I would like to avoid this code duplication.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can reduce the code duplication? Maybe a C# keyword like `readonly`, or some other language feature? Or is this just not possible? Unfortunately, it is not possible to refactor the algorithms such that I can delay instantiation of all objects until all values are known. Think of bidirectional relationships with immutable objects at each end if you need an example of this scenario.

Comment: why can't you have this code defined as the base class and inherit your other classes from the base class?

Comment: Because I'm working with multiple disparate types, and for multiple properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just encapsulate the behavior in its own type:

```
public sealed class OneTimeAssignable<T> where T : class
{
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return mValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if( mValue != null ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Value can only be assigned once." );

            mValue = value;
        }
    }

    private T mValue;
}
```

Now you can use it as the backing field for your properties:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly OneTimeAssignable<AnotherClass> mReference = new OneTimeAssignable<AnotherClass>();
    public AnotherClass Reference
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mReference.Value;
        }
        internal set
        {
            this.mReference.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I have it set to only work on reference types (and assuming you don't want them to ever be set to `null`), but it's easy enough to modify it to accept value types as well, but requires adding a `bool` to track whether the property has been set.

Comment: Brilliant. I am almost literally smacking myself for not thinking of this. Pity readonly doesn't work for auto-generated properties, but that is probably asking too much of C#. I especially like your note about how to make it work with values types.

Comment: @wizard07KSU As of C# 6 you can have readonly auto-properties: `public AnotherClass Reference { get; }` is valid. Again, though, these are limited to being initialized via the constructor.  You can't initialize them later.

Comment: Just recently switched to C# 6.0 (business lags behind the tech curve), so I didn't know about the new feature. I should go read the changelog for C#... thanks!