# How to pass value to base constructor in C# only after some manipulation

Tags: c#, .net

Ok, this question has been answered in SO and here is the [How to pass value to base constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-the-base-constructor-in-c-sharp)

```
public SMAPIException( string message) : base(message)
{
    TranslationHelper instance = TranslationHelper.GetTranslationHelper; // singleton class
    string localizedErrMessage = instance.GetTranslatedMessage(message, "" );
    // code removed for brevity sake.
}
```

But suppose I want to manipulate the "message" info and then set the base class constructor, then how to do it.

Pseudo code below:

```
public SMAPIException( string message) : base(localizedErrMessage)
{
    TranslationHelper instance = TranslationHelper.GetTranslationHelper; // singleton class
    string localizedErrMessage = instance.GetTranslatedMessage(message, "" );
    // code removed for brevity sake.
}
```

// So basically I want the localizedErrMessage to be sent instead of message to base class constructor, is it possible? Please guide me.

Comment: You can create a method that takes the message changes it and returns that and call it in your base constructor like `: base(MakeChanges(message))`.

Comment: @juharr: so in many files I need to do this, so do I need to replicate this small helper method all across my code.

Comment: why don't you just manipulate the message within the base constructor instead of the child class? Especially if TranslationHelper is a singleton....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying parameter values before sending to Base constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651444/modifying-parameter-values-before-sending-to-base-constructor)

Comment: @Unbreakable Just make it an helper method in a static class and reuse it as needed.

Comment: @juharr: Yes that works. Thank you for the inputs. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class SMAPIException : Exception
{
    public SMAPIException(string str) : base(ChangeString(str))
    {
        /*   Since SMAPIException derives from Exceptions we can use 
         *   all public properties of Exception
         */
        Console.WriteLine(base.Message);
    }

    private static string ChangeString(string message)
    {
        return $"Exception is: \"{message}\"";
    }
}
```

**Note** that `ChangeString` has to be `static` !

Example:

```
SMAPIException ex = new SMAPIException("Here comes a new SMAPIException");

//  OUTPUT //
// Exception is "Here comes a new SMAPIException"
```

Inspecting your `BaseType`:

```
// Summary:
//     Initializes a new instance of the System.Exception class with a specified error
//     message.
//
// Parameters:
//   message:
//     The message that describes the error.
public Exception(string message);
```

Calling `base(string message)` is the same as `new Exception("message")`

So you can get the passed value using the `Message`-Property.

**BUT !** this only works if `SMAPIException` does not hide it's base member `new string Message  {get; set;}` **!**

Comment: @FelixD.: Ok, I want to access the same manipulated string in my derived class constructor too, is it possible, intellisense says I have something like base.Message (Is it same as the manipulated string), if not how to access the same manipulated string in derived constructor. Kindly note that I dont want to call the helper method again in derived class.

Comment: @MattRowland : Can you kindly guide me, how to have access to that manipulated string in derived class too. Kindly note that SMAPIException derives from `Exception` C Csharp class.

Comment: I see. So in Message property of base class the `ChangeString(str)` message gets set. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have a static factory method, and make the constructor private:

```
class SMAPIException
{
    private SMAPIException(string message) : base(message)
    {
        // whatever initialization
    }

    public static SMAPIException CreateNew(string message)
    {
        string localizedErrMessage;
        // do whatever to set localizedErrMessage

        return SMAPIException(localizedErrMessage);
    }
}
```

You can then use:

```
SMAPIException localizedEx = SMAPIException.CreateNew("unlocalizedString");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your static method in the parameter list of the base class constructor.

```
public SMAPIException( string message) 
      : base(TranslationHelper.GetTranslationHelper.GetTranslatedMessage(message, ""))
{
}
```

Comment: This way he will create a new TranslationHelper 100 times.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno: KIndly note that translationshelper is singletonclass